# Passing An Array Of Objects To A Function

Tags: c#, arrays, function, object, methods

I have a class called "Tiles".

```
public class Tiles
{

    public int cordX, cordY, tileID;
    Booleans someBooleans;
    public constructor(int X,int Y,int ID)
}
```

The program creates a 2D-grid and stores information (XY-position, tileID) in an array of objects of the Tiles class. Like this:

Create new object array

```
Tiles[] tileArray = new Tiles[totalGridSize];
```

Loop through twice to instantiate the individual elements in the object array

```
tileArray[X + Y] = new Tiles(xPos, yPos, ID);
```

So far everything is working as expected . But now i want to pass elements of the tileArray to a function. (is it okay for the function to be static?)

```
public static void tileStatusChecker(Tiles x[])<---
{    

    Console.WriteLine("Position is {0}X and {1}Y. ID=={2}", x.cordX, x.cordY, x.tileID)    
}
```

== This give me the error:

> Error  CS1552  Array type specifier, [], must appear before parameter name

fair enough, that must be easy to fix.

```
public static void tileStatusChecker(Tiles[] x)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Position is {0}X and {1}Y. ID=={2}", x.cordX, x.cordY, x.tileID)    
}
```

Now the compiler is really mad at me: *CS1061   'Tiles[]' does not contain a definition for 'tileID' and no extension method 'tileID' accepting a first argument of type 'Tiles[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Simultaneously the compiler is also mad at me for calling the function in the first place, declaring the array was never created.

```
Tiles.tileStatusChecker(tileArray[7]);
```

> CS0103 The name 'tileArray' does not exist in the current context

I have a standard "learn c# and visual studio" book next to me but object arrays aren't covered at all. And I think the actual error here is me not really knowing what I'm doing. So can anyone tell me how to pass an array of objects to a method? I don't want to just copy+paste the code and have someone fix it for me. I tried to find a solution here on stackoverflow but ended up with 10,214 results after searching for "C# object array to function" or similar.

Comment: Please take more time to format your code. You've got no indentation at all, and at one point you've got the body of a method on the same line as `{`. You should be aiming to make the question as easy as possible to read.

Comment: But it sounds like you're really not interested in passing a whole array, but a single tile. Just change `Tiles[]` to `Tile` and that should fix both problems. After all, the value of `tileArray[7]` is a `Tiles` reference, not an array... and the idea of printing out "the position of an array" is meaningless. Now would be a good time to look up .NET naming conventions, too.

Comment: Well I suggest you get your IDE to format the code, and make sure it looks like that in the question. (It's not clear what Booleans is either...)

Comment: Oh, and it sounds like you don't have a `tileArray` variable in scope where you're calling the method. Unfortunately as you've only given us snippets instead of a [mcve] we can't easily tell what's wrong there.

Comment: i was trying to make it readable, guess i messed that up @JonSkee but yeah i am trying to pass a single object of the array to the function. I thought i could simplify it as well for the sake of keeping the question short.

Comment: So your title is incorrect - you're just trying to pass a single reference, which happens to have come from an array. You're not trying to pass an array reference at all. The method doesn't care that the value came from an array.

Comment: i'll delete the question and maybe i'll manage to find the error myself. Tried to keep the question short and simple but archived quite the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Whoops, I missed a minor detail and answered your question totally backwards. It is clear now that you do not actually want to hand an Array into your function, given that you called your function with a proper accessor reference. If you rewrite your function to take a `Tiles` rather than a `Tiles[]`, you should be good. All of your problems are arising because your code expects `x` to be a `Tiles` while your function declaration expected `x` to be a `Tiles[]`.

Feel free to ignore the following code chunk, but do definitely hit the note at the end.

Your second shot was better than your first attempt, handing in an array to a function should indeed look like

```
public static void tileStatusChecker(Tiles[] x)
```

but your following code, which attempts to get values like "x.cordX", will not find them - Arrays do not have a .CordX; Tiles(s) have a .CordX. If you want to actually get a Tiles, you would want, say, the first (or technically the 'zeroeth') element in x, which is x[0]. E.G. the first Tiles's CordX would be x[0].CordX.

Side-note:
It often helps me in writing and talking about my code to choose names that fit the grammatical structure of the thing I'm naming. If it's an object, I usually call it something like Object, e.g. if a class represents a tile I would call it "Tile" rather than "Tiles". If you have a second class that represents a collection of Tiles, like a wrapper around a 2-D array (as I have literally done in the past), *then* I would name it Tiles.

Comment: yeah if i change it to tileStatusChecker(Tiles[int] x) and the data the function accesses to x[int].cordY it actually works.

Comment: i'm pretty sure i tried to put it that way, but for some reason it didn't work, probably because i was playing around with the "Static" accessors too much. Now the only thing i need to deal with is this [CS0119 'Tiles' is a type, which is not valid in the given context] error when i'm actually calling the function. But that's standard troubleshooting. Anyway Thx a lot! i was stuck there for 2-3 hours.  finally i can google new error messages.

Comment: http://cube-drone.com/comics/c/progress
 
Tiles.functionName(args); only works if functionName is a static function defined inside the Tiles class.
 
Good luck! Happy to help.